# In Python, is there a way to sort a list made of lists and tuples, consistently?

Tags: python

sort of `a` and `b` are as expected to me, then why is `c` different?  Is there a ways to make it consistent with `a` and `b`, without converting everything to either lists or tuples?

```
>>> a = [(1, 0), (0, 0)]
>>> a.sort()
>>> print a
[(0, 0), (1, 0)]
>>>
>>> b = [[1], (0)]
>>> b.sort()
>>> print b
[0, [1]]
>>>
>>> c = [[1, 0], (0, 0)]
>>> c.sort()
>>> print c
[[1, 0], (0, 0)]
>>>
```

Comment: Interesting question. What are you thinking of using it for?

Comment: Well like I said, I need to sort things, some of them are lists, some of them are tuples, and I don't want to go the extra step of converting all of them one way or another.

Comment: @MarkGaleck I don't think there's any way to avoid doing that though. :\

Comment: Why do you have mixed lists and tuples?

Comment: @user2357112  well, so I want to extend my list by `[ m.span() for m in compiled.finditer(string)]` which yields a list of tuples.  Now, the list has to be kept sorted and mutable, that means it has to be made of lists not tuples, and I have to sort it after extending.

Comment: Then why not convert the new elements to lists as you add them? `a.extend(list(m.span()) for m in compiled.finditer(string))`

Comment: ^ Solves the XY problem. Also it's probably more efficient than using `sorted` with a tuple key.

Comment: @user2357112  Good question! Because, I want to do the whole thing as efficiently as possible (the above is just an SSCCE - the real example uses huge lists and tuples).  What happens, is I do post-processing of the resulting sorted list (of lists and tuples), which I did not needed to mention here, makes it much smaller, and converts the smaller list to list of lists.  But it needs to have the thing sorted first.  So, in order to avoid converting a huge list, I want to sort without converting.

Comment: @Shashank so you are saying, using `sort(key=tuple)` is a performance penalty compared to just `sort`  ?  Like, as if I was converting it explicitly?

Comment: @MarkGaleck: Well, the answer you've accepted is going to do the conversion anyway. I expect the cost of the conversion is going to be negligible compared to the other things eating runtime.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, well I just checked it works (on a small example) - I did not realize it was doing the conversion implicitly.  I guess, there is no other way.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Absolutely yes, there is a performance cost to converting all inner elements to tuples with a key function. By converting everything to a list as you add it to a list, you avoid processing all the lists you initialially had and converting those into tuples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible to convert them only for the purpose of sorting:

```
>>> c = [[1, 0], (0, 0)]
>>> c.sort(key=tuple)
>>> c
[(0, 0), [1, 0]]
```

That being said, a list containing a mix of lists and tuples is a code smell.

Comment: The beautiful thing about this is that since tuples are immutable, `tuple()` of something that's already a tuple doesn't make a copy. So any tuples already in the list *don't use any extra memory* by being used as a key. Sadly, lists that are converted to tuples do need to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure whether the outermost container is a list, you might also want to use:

```
sorted(c, key=tuple)
```

because c.sort() is a list-only function. Just thought I should add that.